# How to synchronize deleted record with backend

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have some records displayed in view, which are fetched from backend server, I want if one record is deleted from backend server, the record displayed should be removed too. I can notify client by websocket from server, but how can I remove the record locally?

I googled all posts and articles, but no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unload` should do it. Try that.